# How to match and replace words for arabic text

Tags: python, regex, replace, match

```
content = "  حَدَّثَنِي أَبُو كَامِلٍ الْجَحْدَرِيُّ ، حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ الْوَاحِدِ ، حَدَّثَنَا الْأَعْمَشُ ، قَالَ : ح وحَدَّثَنَا أَبُو بَكْرِ بْنُ أَبِي شَيْبَةَ و أَبُو كُرَيْبٍ قَالَا : حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو مُعَاوِيَةَ ، عَنْ الْأَعْمَشِ ، عَنْ إِبْرَاهِيمَ التَّيْمِيِّ ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ ، عَنْ أَبِي ذَرٍّ : قَالَ  "

print(content)

import re
bannedWord2 ={ "عَنْ","قَالَ","قَالَا","حَدَّثَنِي" ,"حَدَّثَنَا", "وحَدَّثَنا"    }
re_banned_words = re.compile(r"\b(" + "|".join(bannedWord2) + ")\\W", re.I)

def RemoveBannedWords(toPrint):
    global re_banned_words
    return re_banned_words.sub("", toPrint)

p= RemoveBannedWords(content)

print("after removal")
print(p)
```

unluckily, the word    `وحَدَّثَنا`  does not work.

how to make it work just because it has additional **`و`**
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Your regex alternation includes the following term:

```
وحَدَّثَنا
```

However, the text actually contains this:

```
وحَدَّثَنَا
```

Note carefully that there is a fetHa over the final nun in this word, which your alternation term does not contain.  Include the proper term and you will get the proper output:

أَبُو كَامِلٍ الْجَحْدَرِيُّ ،  عَبْدُ الْوَاحِدِ ،  الْأَعْمَشُ ، قَالَ : ح  أَبُو بَكْرِ بْنُ أَبِي شَيْبَةَ و أَبُو كُرَيْبٍ ا :  أَبُو مُعَاوِيَةَ ، عَنْ الْأَعْمَشِ ، عَنْ إِبْرَاهِيمَ التَّيْمِيِّ ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ ، عَنْ أَبِي ذَرٍّ : قَالَ

Comment: thank you very much..i did not realized the spelling  ;)